# python: how to escape slashes in path?

Tags: python

```
temp_dir = 'spam'
dir_name = 'foo/bar/baz.xyz'  # should be escaped somehow
dir = os.path.join(temp_dir, dir_name)
os.mkdir(dir)
```

I need to create directory inside `temp_dir` with name `dir_name`. But current code will produce 3 nested dirs inside `temp_dir`.

I've tried to replace each slash in `dir_name` with `\/` but `os.mkdir` ignores escaping with `\` and treat it as part of nested dir name.

Comment: Or if you insist, use os.sep. Using / or \ is not good practice.

Comment: I did, you can use join to combine all of the parts and not just two of them.

Comment: How to fix this: don't use / or  \ in dirNames, when instead you could use _

Comment: Oh Hahaha, you want the directory name to contain slashes. That’s not a good idea.

Comment: @Aiven: Not sure if your really want slashes in the directory name, can you explain the rationale behind it?

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this, but if you really want this and the OS supports it, I would attempt to go through `subprocess.call()` or similar. Not sure what command you'd actually be calling, but it sounds like you have that part handled.

Comment: Note that if you're on a Mac, slashes in a filename are legal, and they are presented to as colons outside of Finder. (Colons are path separators on Mac.) So if you have a file called `a/b.txt`, you can access it as `Path("a:b.txt")` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Python issue, but an OS issue. Your OS will not support folder names containing slash characters.

Comment: @Aiven yes/I/am

Comment: but how did i create dir with slashes manually (see link to screenshot)? or not every OS support such feature?

Comment: @Aiven: not every OS supports such feature. What is your platform ?

Comment: Yves-Daoust, darwin

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) you can check which filesystem has `/` in the 'allowable characters for directory entries'.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this. In another way what would be a difference for OS between 'foo/bar/baz.xyz' as a file and 'foo/bar/baz.xyz' as a folder? I think it is a bad idea and you won't find a solution.

Comment: i can create directory with name `foo/bar.xyz` manually. but is it possible to make it programmatically? btw OS can distinguish directory from file without looking up its name

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.01. 
Via terminal:
`mkdir foo/bar.xyz`
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo/bar.xyz’: No such file or directory`.
Manually:
`Folder names can't content '/'`.

"OS can distinguish directory from file without looking up its name."
What do you mean? Try to make `cd foo/bar.xyz` what will you see? 

What OS do you use?

Comment: > OS can distinguish... i mean that each file/dir have specific bit in meta info that will tell you if this is directory or file. try `ls -la`: `drwx...` for dirs  and `-rw-...` for files

Comment: yes, it is true. But I meant how you will work with that if all commands which are working with files won't understand what you mean: file or dir.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory name contains a slash the OS module sees this as a `:`. Therefore you can create dirs containing slashes by specifying the dirname as followed `os.mkdir(path + "dir:name")`. The folder will be named dir/name.

Comment: or better use `os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, "dir1", "dir2", "dir3"))`. It will be like `path/dir1/dir2/dir3` in linux and `path\dir1\dir2\dir3` in windows